# How to drain the java thread stack memory area?

Tags: java, c, memory-management, operating-system, jvm

In C, I can drain the stack memory area with following small program(the limit of stack size in my Mac is 8MB)

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  int a[1024*1024*2];
  long size = sizeof(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Since array is java is also an object, its element are stored in heap. According to [Oracle's doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) , the default thread stack size is 512KB in Mac. Is there any program can drain the stack size ?

Comment: You want to cause a stack overflow? `void func() { func(); }` will do nicely.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {main(args);}` ?  If you explained why/what you are actually trying to accomplish we might be able to help with something more useful in Java.

Comment: What I am trying to do is verifying that the thread stack size is 512KB.

Answer (score 1):

Stack values only exist within the scope of the function they are created in. Once it returns, they are discarded.

Now Java only stores primitives on the stack.

So they only way to drain the stack would be to create primitives.  In this is a `recursive method` then I guess you could observe some drain before a StackOverflowError.